# Responsive layout not scrolling vertically in short screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a site I designed and coded that seems to cut off top and bottom on very specific devices that have short screens AND WILL NOT SCROLL. Any ideas on that I can do to keep the picture centered in the browser without any overlapping

Here's a link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/SCATORY/mjyssu7y/

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="container">
<div class="nav">
    <div class="logo"></div>

</div>
</div>
    <div class="container holder">
    <div class="center">
    <div class="height">
    <h1>Practice yoga. <br>In hypo-microbial style.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bag">
    </div>
    <div class="height-2">
    <h2>Introducing ThePureBag™.<br>
The germ-resistant way to carry your yoga gear in style.</h2>
<div class="margin">
<a href="mailto:"><button class="contact">Contact Us</button></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grey">
    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the `position:fixed` off of the `#container` and take the `position:absolute` off of the `.holder`. This should make it work.

Position:fixed means that the element won't scroll.